# Remote connection string to database fails for username, but can access via Studio Manager

Tags: sql-server, powershell, database-connection

Whilst my Windows AD account has datareader access to a SQL 2012 database (can access via SQL Studio Manager, perform queries etc), my login seems to fail when I try to perform the same query via a SQL connection through a Powershell script.

So I log into the Computer with my AD Account, same as specified in UID in the connection string, and Powershell is launched under the same account.

This is the SQL Query invoked within Powershell:

```
$ADComputer='Server1'
$sqlParameters = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter('@ServerName', $ADComputer)
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=<servername>;Database=<databasename>;Uid=<domain\user>;Pwd=<password>"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

$SqlCmd.CommandText = 
"SELECT TOP 1 MAX(CIA.EnforcementDeadline) AS EnforcementDeadline
FROM v_collection, v_FullCollectionMembership FCM 
INNER JOIN v_Collection COL  
ON FCM.CollectionID = COL.CollectionID 
INNER JOIN v_CIAssignment CIA
WHERE FCM.CollectionID NOT IN ('SMS00001','SMSDM003')
AND FCM.Name='$ADComputer'"

$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlConnection.Close()
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$DataSet.Tables[0]
$LastUpdateDate = $DataSet.Tables[0]
$LastUpdate = $LastUpdateDate | Select Column1 -Expandproperty Column1

Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Login failed for user '<domain\user>'."
```

It's as if the connection string doesn't notice what's specified.

However, if I remove the UID and PWD and add "Integrated Security" it then works:

```
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=<servername>;Database=<databasename>;Integrated Security=SSPI"
```

I have also discovered that the line

```
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
```

Is where the error occurs. Admittedly, I don't consider myself a guru in PS as I am learning, but it sounds as if this could be writing something somewhere that may cause write permission issues?

Hope someone can help or at least explain why it's failing.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't login to SQL Server using a domain account specified in the connection string.

You can either specify user name and password in the connection string using a SQL authentication user (if you enabled Mixed Mode Authentication on the server) or specify "Integrated Security=True" to use current process credentials.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669066(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks - that explains why. My script runs under a service account, that doesn't have access to the database, but my domain account does, which is why I am able to run it using IS.